# Is it possible to modify jss deploy template

Tags: jss

We have stopped using code first jss. But we would still like to have commands like jss deploy template / jss deploy component. Unfortunately, these commands do stuff we don't want them to do, like add workflows to the templates and setting the app root/placeholders to locked.

Is it possible to modify these commands, and if it is, how could we modify them so:

- templates are generated without workflow
- no items are locked
- additional templates have their placeholder settings updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do that you would need to modify the import process itself. The import process is using a few pipelines defined in `Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices.config`:

[image]

Each of those has plenty of processors. You would need to override some of them in order to adjust it to your needs.

1. To get rid of the workflow from being assigned to templates you can:

   - override `ProcessTemplates` processor
   - for this particular change, you can also take a look at default app configuration and remove default workflow path form `defaultWorkflow` attribute in `Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Apps.config` (would be better to override that property in  your app configuration)
2. If you would like not to protect items I would suggest looking and overriding `ProtectDeveloperItems` processor
3. For placeholder settings items - take a look at `AddPlaceholderAllowedControls` or `ProcessPlaceholders`